# Hangfire jobs stuck in processing state

Tags: hangfire

We are using Hangfire to download data from Azure. We are using Hangfire 1.7.6. However, after running for some time, Hangfire is having a deadlock and seems stuck in processing the job. We had to restart the service to keep it working.

There is a recurring job which is adding jobs to the other background server. Mostly the jobs are stuck when it is downloading a big file.

Has anyone faced this type of problem of hangfire jobs stuck in processing?

Please let me know if any further information is required. Any help/guidance is appreciated.

Comment: How is your Hangfire hosted ? (IIS ?)

Comment: Hello @jbl, I am using it as a windows service.

Answer (score 0):

Is this not caused by the length of time it takes to complete the download from azure?

You could try testing this with large files, and see how it handles it.

Also, like @jbl asked, how is your Hangfire Server hosted? If it is hosted in IIS then remember that the Hangfire Server may lose its heartbeat if IIS shuts down the application process due to it being idle for a given period of time.

I came across this issue in the past and ended up running the application as a process on the server.

IIS is optimised to save resources, so it will shutdown processes that aren't being used. When a request is made to your application, then it fires the process back up. This will also cause any scheduled background jobs not to fire.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @Derek I am deploying as windows service.

Comment: Then i would investigate the length of time the job takes to run on a large file when you are downloading from Azure, I've not used Hangfire for sometime, but perhaps a job has a timeout that your'e exceeding? test this with a large file.